# Espaço em uma String C

Tags: c, string

Estou começando a aprender C, e me deparei com a seguinte duvida:

Quando eu peço para o usuário me informar uma musica ou artista, ele acaba me informando uma musica com espaços, tipo `"AS I AM"`, porem o programa pula a parte da musica e do artista, como resolver isso?

```
printf("MUSICA: "); 
scanf("%s", novo->nome);
printf("ARTISTA: "); 
scanf("%s", novo->artista);
printf("ANO: "); 
scanf("%d", &novo->ano);
```

Comment: typedef struct musica{
   char nome[100];
   char artista[100];
   int ano;
   struct musica *prox;
}musica;

Comment: A resposta ja solucionou seu problema, eu esqueci de remover meu comentário.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

o `scanf` aceita diversas estruturas diferentes para efetuar a entrada de valores, e para se capturar uma linha inteira, você deve usar uma estrutura que faça a leitura até um carácter especifico.

```
char line[500];
scanf("%[^\n]",line);
```

Os colchetes "[" e "]", informam que terá uma condição, o "^" indica que deve recolher tudo que for digitado até chegar ao "\n".

Comment: Sem especificar o tamanho do buffer na string de formatação, existe o risco de ocorrer um *[buffer overflow](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=scanf+buffer+overflow)*. O correto para esse exemplo é `scanf("%499[^\n]", line);`

Comment: disso eu não sabia, será bem útil para mim.

Comment: @Gomiero é mais seguro usar o `fgets` neste caso, `fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)` é uma otima forma de evitar o buffer overflow.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho: Exato!  Sempre é melhor utilizar o `fgets` para obter uma entrada do usuário do que o `scanf` :)

Comment: mas se a variável for um ponteiro de char, não conseguiria pegar o tamanho através  do `sizeof` e muita das vezes se usa ponteiros de char dentro de structs.